# Issues with installed plugins like cordova-sqlite-storage

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Every time I try to run my Ionic app, it is unable to load native plugins like the Cordova SQLite plugin and the Splash Screen plugin.

This happens at this line of code:

```
this.dbLocal.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts(id INTEGER 
PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nickname TEXT, firstName TEXT, lastName TEXT, 
description TEXT)', {}).then(console.log('Contacts loaded'));
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): plugin_not_installed
```

I also notice in the console logs that it is unable to find the native SQLITE plugin despite it being installed in the Ionic project. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, as well as doing:

```
ionic cordova prepare
```

But it still does not work. I am not sure how to resolve this issue. Currently we are using:
[image]

Comment: Refer answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910524/ionic-cordova-plugin-ionic-plugin-is-not-installed-when-ionic-plugin-add-says/47133594#47133594

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are testing on a browser and sql native plugin is not available at a browser, thats why you get this reason.

You need to test on a real mobile, there it'll work without any problems.

Comment: I tested this out on an actual Android device(API 25) using                     
ionic cordova run android --device --livereload

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem. I removed the error by correcting my SQL query. 
Crosscheck your queries.