# Ionic 'Install the HTTP plugin', but it is already installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im trying to do a post on Ionic app, but it keeps saying plugin_not_install. I'm aware that there was a referencing issue to the actual cordova plugin but I've checked the references and it all seems to be fine. Also just to note, Im testing this on the Ionic DevApp which is installed on an iPhone

This is the error its giving me:

```
Native: tried calling HTTP.post, but the HTTP plugin is not installed. 

Install the HTTP plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http'
```

I've ran the command multiple times and still the same result.

And I've also ran `npm install --save @ionic-native/http` and verified that the files exist for both `node_modules/@ionic-native/http` && `node_modules/cordova-plugin-advanced-http`

This is the system version

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2
Cordova Platforms  : browser 5.0.1 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.9.1
npm  : 5.5.1 
OS   : Linux 4.4
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: Refer-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910524/ionic-cordova-plugin-ionic-plugin-is-not-installed-when-ionic-plugin-add-says/47133594#47133594

Comment: Does not solve it, I've also ran into the same issue using PhotoViewer...

Answer (score 0):

There might two possible fixes for the above mentioned problem.

1. Check whether the plugin is called after the platform.ready().
2. Even after it, if doesn't work or show the same error then follow this method.

   ```
   // Declare Cordova as a global constant

   declare const cordova;

   // directly call the cordova pulgin using "cordova.pulgin.http"

   cordova.plugin.http.post(apiUrl, {}, {},
   response => {},
   response => {})
   ```