# Ionic LocalNotification open when app closed : fireQueudEvent give plugin_not_installed error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, localnotification

I am trying to use the Ionic Cordova LocalNotification plugin. Everything works like a charm when the application is on foreground or in background : the application catch the event

```
this.localNotifications.on('click').subscribe((notification) => { ... }
```

But when the application is closed and I open it with a notification I don't go throw this method as the event is not subscribed yet. I found a method to fire the queued notification :

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.localNotifications.fireQueudEvent().then(() => { .. }
}
```

But when using this method I got this error :

> plugin_not_installed

Does someone have a clue on how to debug/solve this problem ?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910524/ionic-cordova-plugin-ionic-plugin-is-not-installed-when-ionic-plugin-add-says/47133594#47133594